# Without replacing previous columns and values/data how to insert values/data in csv fromat in android?

Tags: android, csv

Is there any way, without replacing previous columns and values/data how to insert values/data in csv format in android?.Let me explain in brief what I actually want, I want to create a excel sheet in android for that I am saving the data in csv format because "if I am right saving in csv produce the same output as in excel", But the problem is that whenever I insert the a new data my previous columns and values/data get replaced, which should not to be actually. So any HELP will really be appreciated THANKS A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [append flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) to true when doing your file write.